# React Mobx - Change store from other store not render observer components

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have to update `@observable` variable by `@action` function on one store.
When I call this `@action` from `component` class it change the `@observable` variable and re-render the `@observer` components.
But when I try to Call this `@action` from `@action` in **other store**, by using callback, the `@observable` variable is changed but `@observer` components not re-render.

One Store:

```
class OneStore {
   @observable variable;

   @action
   setVariable(value) {
      this.variable = value;
   }
}
```

Other Store:

```
class OtherStore {

   @action
   setVariable(callBack, value) {
      callBack(value); //callBack is oneStore.setVariable
   }
}
```

`@observer` Component:

```
@inject('oneStore')
@observer
class ObserverComponent extends Component {

   render() {
      if (this.props.oneStore.variable) {
         return (
            <div> {this.props.oneStore.variable} <div/>
         );
      } else { return null; }
   }
}
```

I tried also to get the variable by `@computed` get function, it still not re-render.

Comment: Please attach a fiddle/sandbox with an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to add bound to the action - `@action.bound` and it simply works...

I think the `this` of OneStore was destroyed after nesting the callback.

The correct code is:

```
class OneStore {
   @observable variable;

   @action.bound
   setVariable(value) {
      this.variable = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Though this architecture is not recommended, this is a correct answer